# Copy of normal and array formulas in one macro

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have the following Excel table:

```
     A                 B                    C                    D                       E
1                     Purchase Price        Sales Price      Purchase Price > Sales Price
2     Product A            50                    40        ={COUNT(IF(ISNUMBER(B2:B10),IF(B2:B10>C2:C10-10,B2:B10)))}
3     Product B            60                    65
4     Product C            80                    60
5     Product D            10                    20
6     Product E            50                    30
7                      =If(A7="";"";60)
```

Now I want use the following Macro to copy the formulas from cell B2:D7 into cell E2:G7:

```
Sub Copy_Option_01 ()
Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("B2:D7").Copy
Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("E2:G7").PasteSpecial xlFormulas
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

This macro copies the formulas from cell B2:D7 into cell E2:G7. However, it also changes the reference of the cells so for example it changes the formula in cell B7 and D2 to:

```
B7    =If(D7="";"";60)
D2    ={COUNT(IF(ISNUMBER(E2:E10);IF(E2:E10>F2:F10-10;E2:E10)))}
```

I want to achieve that the reference of the cell is not changed and they remain as they are in the formula in cell B7 and D2. Therefore, I tried to use the following macro instead:

```
Sub Copy_Option_02 ()
Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("E2:G7").Formula = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("B2:D7").Formula
End Sub
```

This macro copies the formulas from cell B2:D7 into cell E2:E7 and does not change the reference of the cells. However, it also does not copy the {} of the array formula in cell D2.

Do you guys have any idea what macro I can use so

(1) the cell reference of the copied cells is not changed and (2) the {} of the array formula in cell D2 is also copied.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change your original formula to have absolute column references.

> =COUNT(IF(ISNUMBER($B2:$B10),IF($B2:$B10>$C2:$C10-10,$B2:$B10)))

Change Formula to FormulaArray

```
Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("E2:G7").FormulaArray = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("B2:D7").Formula
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, when I use this formula the reference of the copied cells is still changing and it also puts {} around the formula in cell B2 but the formula in cell B2 should stay without {}.